# Executing code if column count is less than 2 datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm using a datagridview to display data from tables (if one button is clicked, display data from the table, if another is clicked, display from another table) but I'm having trouble with setting the values inside textboxes from the datagridview columns. For example, if the column count is greater than 2, grab the ones from the one table, if it is not, then grab the ones from the other table, but it is always executing the greater than 2 statement even when the data table has a different source.

Here is my code:

```
    #region sets the textbox values to the values inside the datagrid
    private void qbcDataGridView_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (qbcDataGridView.Columns.Count > 2) {
            id = Convert.ToInt32(qbcDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            householdHead_textBox.Text = qbcDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            spouse_txtbox.Text = qbcDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            textBox_familyMembers.Text = qbcDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            textBox_anniversary.Text = qbcDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            addressTxtBox.Text = qbcDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            textBox_phone.Text = qbcDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            textBox_status.Text = qbcDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        } 
        else
        {
            id = Convert.ToInt32(qbcDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            textBox_bname.Text = qbcDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            textBox_birthday.Text = qbcDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

As you can see (hopefully) when I load the other table (birthdays), and fire up the `qbcDataGridView_RowHeaderMouseClick`, it is throwing an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when it comes to textBox_familyMembers.Text, but I want it to execute the else statement since the birthdays table is in the datagridview.

If it helps, here is the button click event code for grabbing the data from the birthday table:

```
 private void viewBirthdays_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        dbConn.Open();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();


        DbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select id, full_name, birthdate from birthdays", dbConn);
        DbAdapter.Fill(dt);

        qbcDataGridView.DataSource = dt;

        qbcDataGridView.Columns[0].Visible = false; // hide id field

        dbConn.Close();

        // hide members 
        nameLbl.Hide();
        householdHead_textBox.Hide();

        label_spouse.Hide();
        spouse_txtbox.Hide();

        label_familyMembers.Hide();
        textBox_familyMembers.Hide();

        label_anniversary.Hide();
        textBox_anniversary.Hide();

        label_address.Hide();
        addressTxtBox.Hide();

        label_phone.Hide();
        textBox_phone.Hide();

        label_status.Hide();
        textBox_status.Hide();

        // show the birthday fields
        label_bname.Show();
        textBox_bname.Show();

        label_birthday.Show();
        textBox_birthday.Show();
    }
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How many columns are in your birthday table? I'm counting three. If that's the case, the column count is always > 2.

Comment: What is the value of `qbcDataGridView.Columns.Count`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You should likely change `> 2` to `> 3`.

#### Other info

If there are *exactly* two columns, you will go into your `else` block.

```
id = Convert.ToInt32(qbcDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
textBox_bname.Text = qbcDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
textBox_birthday.Text = qbcDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
```

Unfortunately, the above code will only work if there are *three or more* columns (due to the use of `.Cells[2]`). You may want to consider adding a `try..catch` in your else block.

I think part of the issue is that this line:

```
qbcDataGridView.Columns[0].Visible = false; // hide id field
```

hides the first column. So it **looks** to you like there is only two columns, when in fact there are three (of which one is hidden).

Comment: That's what I'm seeing too. Perhaps confusion between cell index (highest is two) and column count (three).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287879(v=vs.71).aspx - basically the highest cell index will always be one less than the count (assuming the array / collection is not empty). `C# arrays are zero indexed`. So if column count is 2 then the indices will be 0 and 1 (but not 2).